# Imgix module in Drupal

Tags: drupal, ftp, drupal-7, composer-php, drupal-modules

I am new in drupal and using in FTP server and no local drupal site. I want to install imgix module in Drupal. And composer manager is required also. I have existing vendor folder under themes/xyz/vendor. How should I do install imgix in FTP. Anyone has install imgix module with composer manager. I did not find any clear information about installation. Anyone has install imgix in drupal has better idea. Thank You.

ref: https://www.drupal.org/project/imgix

Answer (score 0):

If it's for Drupal 7, as you tagged your question you should install modules to `sites/all/modules`, not in theme directory. Try uploading that composer module there (over FTP) and enabling it. If it works do the same for imgix module.

Comment: if possible, can you please explain me in details.

Comment: Download module you need, unpack it. Connect to server over FTP (i.e. with Filezilla), go to sites/all/module on you site (over FTP), copy your module there. Go to modules in back-end, find and enable your module.